# Validate username in html

Tags: javascript

I want that the textbox followed by username should accept only alphabets or digits or their combination.If user enters anything except alphabets or digits then alert dialog box should appear when button is clicked.My code is:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form name="f1">
 username <input type="text" name="tb1"><br>
 <input type="button" value="validate" onclick="val()">
 </form>

 <script>
 function val()
 {
if(document.f1.tb1.value=="")
    alert('Enter username!');
 }
 </script>

 </body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: You need to have a look at `RegExp`

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex in your `val` function:

```
function val()
{
    if(document.f1.tb1.value=="")
        alert('Enter username!');
    if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(document.f1.tb1.value))
        alert('Username must only consist of letters and numbers')
}
```

What this line does is look to see if the string you pass to `test` has anything other than a-z, A-Z, and 0-9.  If it does, then it gives the alert.  If you're willing to accept an underscore as a valid character, then the `if` becomes much simpler:

```
if(/[\W]/.test(document.f1.tb1.value))
```

`\w` is a shortcut that represents all numbers, characters, and the underscore.  The `[^...]` syntax means "any character that doesn't match this list.  `\W` actually is a shortcut for `[^\w]`, and looks for anything that isn't A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _.

**Edit, per your comment**

If you only want to accept alphabetic characters, you just test for the a-z instead of adding the 0-9 in your expression:

```
if(/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(document.f1.tb1.value))
```

This checks the value of `document.f1.tb1.value` to see if it has anything that's not a letter, i.e. anything outside of a-z and A-Z.

There is lots of documentation out there regarding regular expressions.  Once you understand the concept, I use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as a reference.

Comment: If I want that only alphabets or a combination of alphabets and digits should be accepted , then what should I do?

Comment: The code I already listed shows how to check that it's only alphabetical or digits.  I've added an edit that shows how to check that it's only alphabetical.

Comment: For A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _ you have mantioned to use following statement: if(/[\W]/.test(document.f1.tb1.value)).If I want to include "." ,then what should I use ?

Comment: `if(/[^\w\.]/.test`... is what you need then. That's "anything that's not letters, digits, _ or ." I put a \ in front of the . because . is a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: If I want to check any string for "." and "_" then what would be the RegExp ?

Comment: That's simply `if(/[\._]/.test`...  What that means is "look for a period (remember, period needs an escape sequence, because it's a special chacter) or an underscore, and if it exists, return true.  At this point, I feel I've answered a lot of regex question.  Have you tried reading up on it, either at MDN or elsewhere?

Comment: It is not working. I have tried this.                          <html>
<body>

<form name="f1">
username <input type="text" name="tb1"><br>

<input type="button" value="validate" onclick="val()">
</form>

<script>
function val()
{
 name = document.f1.tb1.value;
 len=document.f1.tb1.length;
 if(/[\._]/.test(name[len-1]))
  alert('last character should not be . or _');            }
</script>
</body></html>

Comment: if you're simply checking a character, check the character: `var lastChar = name[len-1]; if (lastChar == '.' || lastChar == '_') {...}`.  Regex is powerful, but way more than you need for simply seeing if a character equals a value.

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?:

EDITED:

```
function val()
{
    if(document.f1.tb1.value == null || 
       document.f1.tb1.value == undefined ||
       /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test(document.f1.tb1.value))

      alert('invalid username!');
 }
```

Comment: Why bother with the `+`?  As long as you have one of the characters, the test already fails.  Also, explanations are good.  What does your code do?  How can the user learn from this, instead of copy-pasting?

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein i check that to return false; in the frist, because i was not certainly what happened if null be passed to `.test`

Comment: Checking `if(!document.f1.tb1.value)` checks for truthiness.  It checks if document.f1.tb1 is not null, not undefined, not "", not 0, and not false.  (Speaking of which, if 0 is a valid username, that check would not accept it.)

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein , yes you right that was a bad mistake, i need to check if its equals to `null` or `undefined` exactly

Comment: I make that mistake plenty of times.  Truthiness is useful, but easy to lose track of.